# Can I use this to find out if the year is a leap year or not in python?

Tags: python

```
if year%4==0 and year%100!=0 or year%400==0:    
  print("Leap year.") 
else:     
  print("Not leap year.")
```

I just tried this way and want to know if this is right or not. There are many ways to solve this problem but I want to know if this is right or not.

Comment: _"I want to know if this is right or not"_ - so **test it**. Get some examples that are and aren't leap years, and find out if it gives the right answer.

Comment: Sorry, @BRemmelzwaal I didn't understand the solution you provided can you elaborate on your answer please thank you.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it's giving the right answer.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal 2000 was indeed a leap year: https://www.onthisday.com/date/2000/february/29

Comment: In which case you know the answer: if it works, then yes you can use it.

Answer (score -5):

```
    def is_leap(year):
        
        # variable to check the leap year
        leap = False
    
        # divided by 100 means century year
        # century year divided by 400 is leap year
        if (year % 400 == 0) and (year % 100 == 0):
        
           # change leap to True
            leap = True

        # not divided by 100 means not a century year
        # year divided by 4 is a leap year
        elif (year % 4 ==0) and (year % 100 != 0):
        
            #Change leap to true
            leap = True

        #else not a leap year
        else:      
            pass
    
        return leap
```

Comment: clearly AI generated code.

Comment: This fails in a lot of regards. Not only is the check completely wrong, there is also a lot of unnecessary code.

Comment: It's verbose, but it does seem to actually perform the correct check?